# Split Column and remove NULL

Tags: sql

I have a table like this

[image]

What I am trying to do is split Product column into 2 columns Product and Sub_Product
I use case statement
Product = case when Primary_Product = 1 then Product end
Sub_Product = case when Primary_Product = 0 then Product end
this is what I got

[image]

My Target table is

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: For future questions: sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can self join the table and filter on `PrimaryProduct`:

```
select t1.Customer
    , t1.Product
    , t2.Product Sub_Product
from tbl t1
left join tbl t2
    on t1.Customer = t2.Customer
    --limit t2 to only hold the subproduct records
    and t2.PrimaryProduct = 0
--limit t1 to hold only the primary product records
where t1.PrimaryProduct = 1
```

You can change the `left` join to an `inner` join to only pull in primary products with a subproduct as well.

Example output from SQL Server since no DBMS was specified:

[image: Example Results]

Edit: Adding handling for multiple subproducts into single row

This is specifically for pre-2017 SQL Server, so it is compatible without using `string_agg`. If you tell me your DBMS, I can find another solution but it should be similar.

```
select distinct Customer
    , stuff((select ',' + Product
        from tbl t2
        where t2.Customer = t.Customer
        for xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') Products
from tbl t
;
```

Example Results:

[image: New results for multiple row handling]

Comment: Sub Question. What if I have more than 1 Product and more than 1 Sub_Product for each Customer. I tried the same query but the problem I had is it it has product1 than list of all sub_product then product2 and repeat the list of Sub_Product. Is there any way that I can just group all Product into 1 column and all SubProduct into Sub_Product column. Thank you so much

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. Is that what you meant?